# importing a function defined in a different directory

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.9

Disclaimer: I am studying Python. I am given a task of reusing functions.

the function is simple:

app/utils/calculators.py

```
  def calculate_session(session_type, session_code):
      return 3 # just to save space
```

Now i need to use the function from a different file but for the life of me, I failed to import it. I have already added **init**.py to utils directory, to the app directory as well.

app/tasks/process_sessions.py

```
   from utils.calculators import calculate_session
```

but when I run it, it fails saying module not found. I am in a virtual environment and all the files go in app directory.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to **specify the full path of the file** (including the root directory) and import the specific function. Example below:

```py
from app.utils.calculators import calculate_session
```

This should then import your function, regardless of whether you're using a virtual environment.